# Is any way we can have a click funnels order form that offers credit card and paypal AND integrates into Infusionsoft?

Tags: paypal, infusionsoft

I am using clickfunnel order form and i want to offer credit card and paypal payment and user information need to go into the infusionsoft. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Infusionsoft provides [API](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/) that you can use to save information to this CRM.

In order to save PayPal payment information, you'll need to develop a script that accepts PayPal [IPN notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) about processed payment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the best way to do this, but here are a couple of ideas:

- You could use Braintree to process the payment, since Braintree already accepts both paypal and credit card. And then you can set up an Email integration on the Clickfunnels order form to integrate with an Infusionsoft web form. This won't transfer the credit card information into Infusionsoft, but it will transfer Name and Email into Infusionsoft.
- You could also add a Paypal button to the order form. This will take people to paypal to process the order. And then you might be able to use something like Zapier to move some of the customer's information and order information into Infusionsoft.